# unicode vs character: What is '\x10'

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, luigi

I'm trying to understand why when we were using pandas `to_csv()`, a number 3189069486778499 has been output as "0.\x103189069486778499". And this is the only case happened within a huge amount of data.
When using `to_csv()`, we have already used `encoding='utf8'`, normally that would solve some unicode problems...

So, **I'm trying to understand what is "\x10"**, so that I may know why...
Since the whole process was running in luigi pipeline, sometimes luigi will generate weird output. I tried the same thing in IPython, same version of pandas and everything works fine....

Comment: We're going to need a [MCVE] to have any hope of helping. The fact that only `luigi` has the problem indicates something weird there, but we can't just guess at what part of a *massive* third party library might be responsible.

Comment: For the record, `\x10` is [the "DLE (Data Link Escape)" character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#DLE), which is hardly every used, and highly unlikely to be the intended meaning. It seems more likely that the data is being written with a binary length prefix (`3189069486778499` is exactly 16 characters long, and a binary storage format might use length prefixed text to make it efficient to parse; `\x10` is a raw byte representing the number 16).

Answer (score 0):

Because it's the likely answer, even if the details aren't provide in your question:

It's highly likely something in your pipeline is intentionally producing fields with length prefixed text, rather than the raw unstructured text. `\x103189069486778499` is a binary byte with the value 16 (0x10), followed by precisely 16 characters. The `0.` before it may be from a previous output, or some other part of whatever custom data serialization format it's using.

This design is usually intended to make parsing more efficient; if you use a delimiter character between fields (e.g. a comma, like CSV), you're stuck coming up with ways to escape or quote the delimiter when it occurs in your actual data, and parsers have to scan character by character, statefully, to figure out where a field begins and ends. With length prefixed text, the parser finds a field length and knows exactly how many characters to read to slurp the field, or how many to skip to find the next field, no quoting or escaping required, no matter what the field contains.

As for what's doing this: You're going to have to check the commands in your pipeline. Your question provides no meaningful way to determine the cause of this problem.